# Multi-language support not working on remote host

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, setlocale

I have implemented multi-language support in my application using PHP's `gettext()` function. It's working correctly when testing at localhost, but on remote server there isn't any effect.

I'm using 000webhost that have `gettext()` support enabled, but when trying to change language there isn't any effect.

I have following file structure

```
.
+-- locale/
|   +-- en/
|       +-- LC_MESSAGES/
|           +-- messages.mo
|           +-- messages.po
|   +-- sv/
|       +-- LC_MESSAGES/
|           +-- messages.mo
|           +-- messages.po
+-- index.php
```

and I set language in index like this

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = filter_var($_GET['lang']);

    switch ($lang) {
        case 'fi':
        case 'en':
        case 'sv':
            setcookie('lang', $lang);
            $_COOKIE['lang'] = $lang;
            break;
    }
}

// I18N support information here
$lang = (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : 'fi');
putenv("LANG=" . $lang);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($domain);
```

What would be the difference between localhost and remote server?

Thanks in advance.